# Micrometer proper representation of recurring job

Tags: batch-processing, micrometer

I have spring boot application in which there is an action scheduled to run every 12 minutes. It it a batch job which reads N records and processes them. There will be X successes and Y failures that have to be observed: classic stuff.

Instrumenting as micrometer gauges using atomic integer for N, X and Y seems to make sense but since the configuration published metrics every minute, I get meaningless metrics 11 times then one real metric associated with an actual run of the scheduled task.

For other tasks in the same application, the one minute publishing interval makes perfect sense.
I would expect to have a way to publish the batch's metrics only after an actual run so that each published metric represents the values of an actual run.

How should this be designed in terms of micrometer's API ?
I read the documentation and did not find a good answer.
I google a lot and was not able to find a path for a meaningful solution for this.

The only way I though would be to directly use the underlying metrics API to explicitly publish metrics when they exist. This would be possible in my case with AWS Cloudwatch but would like to stay vendor agnostic using micrometer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you want to *count* the number of successes and failures. For that you should use a `Counter`: https://docs.micrometer.io/micrometer/reference/concepts/counters.html

For example:

```java
try {
    doSomething();
    Counter.builder("batch.job")
        .tags("outcome", "success")
        .register(registry)
        .increment();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    Counter.builder("batch.job")
        .tags("outcome", "failure")
        .register(registry)
        .increment();
}
```

This should produce two counters (if you have both failures and successes):

```
batch_job{outcome="success"} 2
batch_job{outcome="failure"} 1
```

Since this is a counter (monotonic) not a gauge, you can calculate a `rate` (per minute, per 10m, per whatever) out of it using the query language of your metrics backend. For a one minute rate over 15 minutes this means that you will see zero 14 times and a non-zero value 1 time (when your job was running).

You can get a little more data out of this if you use a `Timer` since the `Timer` always includes a `Counter` too: https://docs.micrometer.io/micrometer/reference/concepts/timers.html

If you cannot increment the counter manually because the value is coming to you by calling a method, check out `FunctionCounter` but you need to make sure that the method produces a monotonic value.